# Node JS: node-shedule parser bug

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, unix, cron

This code does not work:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('0,30 7-21 * * *', function(){
    console.log(Date.now());
});
```

If I replace 7-21 with * it starts working. Why and how can I make it work from 7am to 9 pm?

Comment: Please describe "doesn't work". Does the code just never run?

Comment: correct, no output in console after 24hrs waiting

Comment: Check `console.log(j.nextInvocation())` and `console.log(j.pendingInvocations()[0].recurrenceRule)` at the end of the script and see what is the output. You could also try defining the rule as `RecurrenceRule` object instead of using cron syntax, see [docs](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule#user-content-recurrence-rule-scheduling).

Answer (score -1):

Define your package.json file

run the follwoing commands.

```
npm install
npm install node-schedule
node <your js file/app.js>
```

(your sample code above works as expected)

Comment: The TO already states that it works when `*` is used instead of `7-21`, so it can't be the problem that the required module isn't found. Plus, it should be either including `node-schedule` in the `package.json`, then no `npm install node-schedule` is needed, or using `npm install node-schedule --save`.